Are there no graphical desktop MySQL clients in Ubuntu official apt repo?
Basically what the title says. Is there not a single graphical desktop (non-cli non-web) MySQL / MariaDB client that has been accepted into the official Ubuntu apt repository?

Possibly, but what's wrong with installing the classic ones (MySQL Workbench, DBeaver etc), or the less classic ones for that matter via .deb / PPA?

sorry but mysql-workbench-community  IS in my software list.

If somebody wishes to package Workbench for Debian, from whence it will flow into Ubuntu, your contribution will be appreciated by the community. Start the journey at https://mentors.debian.net. Community packaging is how packages are added to Ubuntu. Community maintenance is how packages remain in Ubuntu. Canonical engineers will do the work only for paying customers.

It is more than a MySQL / MariaDB client, but you can install the excellent DBeaver Community either standalone or as an Eclipse plugin. The standalone version is available as a Snap, Flatpak or deb package.
Simpler to use but less powerful, you can give a try to Beekeeper Studio Community Edition available as an AppImage or deb package.
These two tools are not specific to MySQL / MariaDB, so you could also use them with PostgreSQL, SQLite, Oracle and many other database management systems.

As the others commented, there is MySQL Workbench. You can install it via snap package:
sudo snap install mysql-workbench-community

Or if you don't like snap, you can use a .deb package or apt. Check these pages for more details:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-installing-linux.html#wb-installing-linux-installing-deb
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/

